# submit HTML form data from page to another html page using angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I need simple form submit from HTML to HTML page using angularjs. 
I tried using localstorage broadcast service injector etc but not working pls help.

my pluker code is here 
 http://plnkr.co/edit/q3siKVPe9Nt0vXysIYVD?p=preview

**HTML CODE:**

```
<form name="personForm1" action="form2.html" method="post" novalidate>
  <label for="firstNameEdit1">First name:</label>
  <input id="firstNameEdit1" type="text" name="firstName" ng-model="firstName" required /><br />
  <label for="lastNameEdit1">Last name:</label>
  <input id="lastNameEdit1" type="text" name="lastName" ng-model="lastName" required /><br />
  <br />
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

**JS CODE:**

```
angular.module("mainModule", [])
 .controller("mainController", function($scope, $http) {
   $scope.firstname = {};
   $scope.lastname = {};


   $scope.submitData = function(person, resultVarName) {
     var config = {
       params: {
         person: person
     }
   };

   $http.post("Form2.html", null, config)
     .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
       $scope[resultVarName] = data;
     })
     .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
       $scope[resultVarName] = "SUBMIT ERROR";
     });
   };
 });
```

Comment: try using `GET` instead of `POST`, it should add the values to the querystring, so you can access them that way maybe?

Comment: could you elaborate "HTML to HTML page using angularjs"?, i mean you are trying directly post to html page or using a technology like php, aspnet mvc, web forms etc.

Comment: AngularJS is for SPA(Single page applications), so I highly recommend you to change your mind and the structure of your app.

Comment: once I do the form submit from fom1.html it should go to form2.html with submitted data and display there .. for ex: in form2.html it should say  hi username and last name.

Comment: my controller code is here     angular.module("mainModule", [])
                .controller("mainController", function ($scope, $http)
            {
                   $scope.firstname = {};
                 $scope.lastname = {};
   

    $scope.submitData = function (person, resultVarName)
    {
      var config = {
        params: {
          username: username} };
      $http.post("Form2.html", null, config)     pls check it in plunker script.js  to pass data from page to page during from submit

Answer (score 0):

`Angular js` is spa framework, which means there exist only one main html page which could be the `home/default` page of a application and other pages like login/forgot password will be stored as `templates` and rendered inside this main page.

you can think of this process as a `swap-in swap-out` logic, whenever any page is need to rendered, old page(template) is swapped out and a new page(template) will be rendered.

---

Refer to this [plunker](http://embed.plnkr.co/HD2kbjl2DxAXga1yu2oS/) demo to understand this process better.

### Below are some major things from plunker

**Routing code:**

```
app.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
   .when('/home', {
     templateUrl: 'template.html',
     controller: 'Ctrl'
   })
   // route for the welcome/dashboard page
  .when('/welcome/:userName', {
    templateUrl: 'welcome.html',
    controller: 'welcomeCtrl'
  })
  // route for the forgot/Recover password page
  .when('/forgotPass', {
    templateUrl: 'forgotPass.html',
    controller: 'forgotPassCtrl'
  })
  //fallback url if nothing matches
  .otherwise({
    redirectTo: '/home'
  })
}]);
```

Code for navigating to new template, append parameters if any

`$location.path("/welcome/" + $scope.userName);`

There are many advantages of a spa:

- some common components which tend to appear on most of the pages can be placed in main and only the specific html snapshot is swapped-in or swapped-out on main page, this way same piece of code is not duplicated.
- Render time is improved since common components like header/footer is not rendered every time page navigation happens.
- Helps to achieve separation of concern for common components like header/footer, which improves modularity and readability of code.